# duplicate entries on a sub query in left join statement

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have the following SQL query :

```
SELECT band.id bid, band.name, bandInfo.summary, bandImage.url bandImage, 
user.id uid, user.username, userImage.url userImage
FROM bands AS band
INNER JOIN band_info AS bandInfo ON band.id = bandInfo.bid
LEFT JOIN band_image AS bandImage ON band.id = bandImage.bid
LEFT JOIN band_followers AS follower ON follower.bid = band.id
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT user.id FROM users AS user, bands AS band, band_followers AS follower WHERE user.id = follower.uid) AS temp) AND user.activated = 1
LEFT JOIN user_info AS userInfo ON userInfo.uid = user.id
LEFT JOIN user_image AS userImage ON user.id = userImage.uid
WHERE (band.activated = 1) AND (bandInfo.language = 'fr')
ORDER BY band.name
```

which returns me duplicates line.

The goal is to retrieves all users if exists which follows all bands with a limit to do some paginated results.

I have to retrieve :

```
{
    "table": "Table inconnue",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 1,
            "username": "everytimeicob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 2,
            "username": "noob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 2,
            "name": "Veil Of Maya",
            "summary": "Veil of Maya is a good band",
            "bandImage": null,
            "uid": 1,
            "username": "everytimeicob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I retrieve :

```
{
    "table": "Table inconnue",
    "rows":
    [
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 1,
            "username": "everytimeicob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 1,
            "username": "everytimeicob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 2,
            "username": "noob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 1,
            "name": "Children Of Bodom",
            "summary": "Children of Bodom est un groupe de metal finlandais. Les cinq membres du groupe sont originaires d'Espoo, une ville finlandaise voisine d'Helsinki. Le groupe ne s’appelle ainsi que depuis 1997, avant quoi il s’appelait Inearthed. La mascotte du groupe est affectueusement appelée Roy et représente l'image folklorique de la mort, la faucheuse. Il est présent sur toutes les couvertures d'albums jusqu'à présent. &lt;a href="http://www.last.fm/music/Children+of+Bodom"&gt;Read more about Children of Bodom on Last.fm&lt;/a&gt;.",
            "bandImage": "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/87864171/Children+of+Bodom+band.png",
            "uid": 2,
            "username": "noob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 2,
            "name": "Veil Of Maya",
            "summary": "Veil of Maya is a good band",
            "bandImage": null,
            "uid": 1,
            "username": "everytimeicob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxxx"
        },
        {
            "bid": 2,
            "name": "Veil Of Maya",
            "summary": "Veil of Maya is a good band",
            "bandImage": null,
            "uid": 2,
            "username": "noob",
            "userImage": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Anyone get an ideas here ? I have to limit the result of users following bands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below once, tried modifying your query by removing the unnecessary subquery and moving the condition from 
`WHERE` clause to `JOIN ON` clause

```
SELECT band.id as bid, 
band.name, 
bandInfo.summary, 
bandImage.url as bandImage, 
u.id as uid, 
u.username, 
userImage.url as userImage
FROM bands AS band
INNER JOIN band_info AS bandInfo ON band.id = bandInfo.bid AND bandInfo.language = 'fr'
LEFT JOIN band_image AS bandImage ON band.id = bandImage.bid
LEFT JOIN band_followers AS follower ON follower.bid = band.id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT user.id,
user.username
FROM users AS user
WHERE user.activated = 1
LIMIT 10
) u ON u.id  = follower.uid
LEFT JOIN user_info AS userInfo ON userInfo.uid = u.id
LEFT JOIN user_image AS userImage ON u.id = userImage.uid
WHERE band.activated = 1 
ORDER BY band.name;
```

Comment: Yes.. but if I use LIMIT, it'll limit on bands and not on users.id in band_followers

Comment: Not sure I understood. What you mean by if I use LIMIT??? Your subquery is actually not needed as you can join directly with bandfollower.

Comment: I want to limit results provided by the 'LEFT JOIN users ON user.id = follower.uid AND user.activated = 1' because I want to do pagination on users following every bands like have only 10 users and not ALL

Comment: you're just amazing! I tested all solutions except this .. (y)

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN band_followers AS follower ON follower.bid = band.id
LEFT JOIN users AS user ON user.id IN (SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT user.id FROM users AS user, 
bands AS band, band_followers AS follower 
WHERE user.id = follower.uid) AS temp) AND user.activated = 1
```

You are joining too much: all **followers** two times, and **bands** without reason.

If you want all instances of "following", you should logically start with the relevant table:

```
SELECT * from band_followers
```

Then join the band and user tables:

```
SELECT 
    band_followers.uid, 
    bands.id bid, bands.name,
    user.username,
    band_info.summary, band_image.url burl,
    user_image.url uurl
FROM 
    band_followers
    INNER JOIN bands on band_followers.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN band_info on band_info.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN band_image on band_image.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN users on users.id=band_followers.uid
    INNER JOIN user_image on user_image.uid=band_followers.uid
```

INNER JOIN assuming all fields are mandatory.
Finally, add conditions:

```
SELECT 
    band_followers.uid, 
    bands.id bid, bands.name,
    user.username,
    band_info.summary, band_image.url burl,
    user_image.url uurl
FROM 
    band_followers
    INNER JOIN bands on band_followers.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN band_info on band_info.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN band_image on band_image.bid=bands.id
    INNER JOIN users on users.id=band_followers.uid
    INNER JOIN user_image on user_image.uid=band_followers.uid
WHERE 
    bands.activated=1
    AND users.activated = 1
    AND band_info.language = 'fr'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't want all instances of following but all instance of bands even if there isn't any follower but I want to limit too followers instance